# Error with form validation (javascript)

Tags: javascript, validation

I have the following HTML code:

```
<form name="Register" action="Register.aspx" method="post" runat="server" style="margin-top: 15px;" onsubmit="return validateProfile(FormName='Register');" >
  <p> Name* : <input id="FirstName" type="text" name="FirstName"/> </p>
<form>
```

And this JavaScript code:

```
function isEmpty(field) {       
  if (field == "" || field == null)
    return false;
}

function validateProfile(FormName) {
    var errFname = "";
    var Fname = document.forms[FormName]["FirstName"].value;
    alert(isEmpty(field=Fname));
    return false;
}
```

The problem here is that the validation doesn't work...

I want that if the field is empty there will be an alert message.
The solution might be very simple, but I just start leran this validtion with javascript.

I have to used the `isEmpty` function in the code.

Comment: Your code works: http://jsfiddle.net/Uy2ha/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change

```
validateProfile(FormName='Register');
```

to

```
validateProfile('Register');
```

and

```
alert(isEmpty(field=Fname));
```

to

```
   alert(isEmpty(Fname));


function validateProfile(FormName) {
    var errFname = "";
    var Fname = document.forms[FormName]["FirstName"].value;
    return isEmpty(Fname);
}
```

Comment: This won't change much - will it?

Comment: It isn't smart to do it but I can't see why it should cause errors

Comment: Hi, Thank you! But the problem now is that even if the field is empty after submit the form is submiting, how can I preven this?

Comment: can u explain clearly.What is  after submit the form is submiting,

Comment: After click submit, I see the alert, but after closing the the alert, the form is submiting, even that the field is empty...

Comment: Ok, in jsfiddle it works great, but why in my page it didn't work?

Answer (score 1):

You should use the following code:

```
function validateProfile(FormName) {
        var errFname = "";
        var Fname = document.getElementById("FirstName").value;
        alert(isEmpty(Fname));
        return false;
}
```

You can use the id of textfield as you have given it.
And change the form tag with code:

```
<form name="Register" action="Register.aspx" method="post" runat="server" style="margin-top: 15px;" onsubmit="return validateProfile('Register');" >
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript does not allow passing function parameters by name

```
alert(isEmpty(Fname)); // instead of isEmpty(field=Fname)
```